# Plot multiple ROC curves on one plot?

Tags: r, plot, roc

I want to cycle compare several logistic regression models.
And print in one chart several ROC curves.
How I can do this?
For example, for one model it looks like

```
pred_fit4 <- prediction(workData$pred,workData3$value)
perf_fit4 <- performance(pred_fit4,"tpr","fpr")
roc <- plot(perf_fit4,colorize = T, print.cutoffs.at = seq(0,1),)
```

and its curve output as below:

[image]

And how can I add a new line?
It looks like

```
for (...) {
.......
.......
    pred_fit4 <- prediction(workData$pred,workData3$value)
    perf_fit4 <- performance(pred_fit4,"tpr","fpr")
    #need add line on exist chart
    roc <- plot(perf_fit4,colorize = T , print.cutoffs.at = seq(0,1),)
}
```

Comment: have you looked at something like this : par(mfrow=c(nrow,ncol)) ? Where nrow and ncol define the grid of plots

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should be able to add lines to an existing base plot using `lines()` (help `?lines`). There are numerous examples for that on SO. Please get in the habit of providing minimal reproducible (!) examples ready to copy & paste, so that others can play around with it,

Comment: Is this what you want to accomplish? http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html

Comment: When you say *"add a new line"*, do you mean *[the "line of no-discrimination"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic)* from (0,0) to (1,1), or (0,0) to (0.32,1), or where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plot multiple ROC curves for logistic regression model in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584099/plot-multiple-roc-curves-for-logistic-regression-model-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

This is using a package pROC. You can create a ROC object and then add to the same graph using lines and add as many ROC as you want.

```
obj.rpart1=roc(label1 ~ p1.rpart, smooth = T)
obj.rpart2=roc(label1 ~ p1.rpart, smooth = T)
plot(obj.rpart)
lines(obj.rpart2)
```